# Getting Return Value of NULL

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Hey folks I seem to be getting an NULL value returned for the 'mainEntity' => array() in the following peice of code. Tried everything anyone got any ideas? Thinking my variable isn't getting passed to the function correcty.

``````
<?php
  $schema = array(
    '@context'   => "https://schema.org",
    '@type'      => "FAQPage",
    'mainEntity' => array()
    );
// Get Advanced Custom Fields Values 
    if ( have_rows('faq') ) {
      while ( have_rows('faq') ) : the_row();
      if ( have_rows('faq_section') ) {
        while ( have_rows('faq_section') ) : the_row();
          $questions = array(
            '@type'          => 'Question',
            'name'           => get_sub_field('faq_question'),
            'acceptedAnswer' => array(
            '@type' => "Answer",
            'text' => get_sub_field('faq_answer')
              )
              );
              array_push($schema['mainEntity'], $questions);
        endwhile;
      }
    endwhile;
    function faq_schema ($schema) {
      global $schema;
      echo '<!-- FAQ Structured data --><script type="application/ld+json">'. json_encode($schema) .'</script>';
    }
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'faq_schema', 100 );
  }
  ?>`````
``````

Comment: what does @type mean?

Comment: It is impossible to know based on the code given to tell WHY you get a NULL value. We can only guess. If your faq_schema returns null it won't be surprising because you don't actually return anything (return {whatever}}